# Partial Results Error during File Upload – Seeking Assistance (CentOS 8.8, PHP 8.2, WordPress)

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, wordpress, rocky-linux

I hope you're doing well. I'm reaching out because I've hit a roadblock with my WordPress website and file uploads. Here's the error message that has been causing me headaches:

```
[Thu Nov 02 16:55:53.380836 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2247:tid 140163381053184] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client myip:17930] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: http://serverip/wp-admin/upload.php
```

This error pops up every time I attempt to upload files larger than 0.5 MB on my WordPress site. To provide some context, I'm using CentOS 8.8, Apache 2.4, PHP 8.2, and the latest version of WordPress.
[The Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfCYj.png)

I've meticulously reviewed my Apache and PHP configurations, tweaked timeout settings, and confirmed that my server has more than enough resources to handle the task. Despite my efforts, the problem persists.

I've scoured my proxy settings, delved into logs, and scoured forums, but no luck so far. If anyone has faced a similar issue with the latest WordPress version or has any insights on troubleshooting and resolving this problem, I would be immensely grateful for your help.

Thank you all for your time and expertise.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please do not link or post pictures of text you can copy and paste. You may have meticulously reviewed the config but you've not included any details of what is configured in your post here (apache max post size, PHP max upload size, timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

The problem results from the use of a Squid proxy server. Check your network settings. ;)